# Routing in rails 3 - no route matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model called EmployeeTrainingCourse. This is a record of employee training, and all works fine. However, I am trying to setup a mechanism for inputting bulk training at once. So I have a link through to a get action on the employee_training_courses controller, which passes in several employee_ids, and then loads a form. I am then trying to have that form post to a different action on the employee_training_courses controller to actually create all the forms. Hope that makes sense.

The problem is that the form is not "finding" the route. Can someone help out?

Here are the routes

```
  get '/training_update', :to => 'employee_training_courses#training_update', :as => 'training_update'
  put '/process_training_update', :to => 'employee_training_courses#process_training_update', :as => 'process_training_update'
```

and here is a chopped up version of the employee_training_courses controller

```
class EmployeeTrainingCoursesController < EmployeesMainController
  def training_update
    @employees = @current_account.employees.where(:id => params[:employee_id])
    @course = EmployeeTrainingCourse.new
    render :training_update
  end

  def process_training_update
    do stuff in here
  end
end
```

and finally the form itself on the "training_update" haml page

```
  = simple_form_for [@course], :url => url_for(:action => 'process_training_update', :controller => 'employee_training_courses',), :method => 'post' do |f|
    = f.input :name, :label => 'Title'
    = f.submit
```

all that happens when i click submit is that I receive an instant routing error "No route matches "/process_training_update""

and in the server console it reports

```
Started POST "/process_training_update" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-10-21 13:04:01 +0100
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/process_training_update"):
```

appreciate some advice. I think it's something to do with the form but beyond that I do not know. Normally the training controller would get a single employee passed back to it, but in this case that's not happening.

Comment: "put" and "post" are different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're declaring `put` in your routes and using `post` in your view.

So replace:

```
put '/process_training_update'
```

with

```
post '/process_training_update'
```

Comment: I know this feeling very well :)